# Minimum no. of flip flops for the given sequence

Tags: computer-architecture, digital-circuits

> We want to design a synchronous counter that counts the sequence
>   0-1-0-2-0-3 and then repeats. The minimum number of flip-flops
>   required to implement this counter is________

According to me, the answer should be 2, as the max. value in the sequence is 3 and 3 can be repeated with 2 bits only.

But my solution manual says the answer should be 4.

I can't really fathom this answer given by my manual.

Am I right? If not why am I getting a wrong answer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that the sequence has period 6, you certainly need at least 3 bits of memory. Whether you need more depends on your computation model, which you haven't defined. Assuming that two flip-flops would designate the output, you need at least two more since 0 appears three times in the sequence.

Comment: Hi @YuvalFilmus, can you please elaborate about the period thing you talk about in your answer? I find it a little confusing and difficult to grasp. Thank you!

Comment: See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_sequence.